# Possible to invoke ASMX service with parameter via url query string?

Tags: asmx

I've got a asmx service that takes a single int parameter. I can open the URL to the service and see the service description screen. From here I can enter the query parameters into a form and invoke the web service.

Is there any way to invoke a web service directly from a URL/query string?

This doesnt work:

http://localhost:4653/MyService.asmx?op=MyWebMethod&intParameter=1

Any ideas? I'd really like to be able to do this from a standard link due to some deployment issues. Am I going to have to wrap the request in a normal aspx page?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can decorate your method to allow HTTP GET requests, which should in turn do what you're looking for like so:

```
[WebMethod]  
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public string MyNiftyMethod(int myint)
{
    // ... code here
}
```

And edit the web.config :

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
  </protocols>
```

Then you'll be able to call this method like so:

`http://mysite.com/Service.asmx/MyNiftyMethod?myint=12345`

EDIT:  Note that this method of performing GET requests does come with some security risks.  According to the [MSDN documentation for UseHttpGet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.usehttpget.aspx):

> Setting the **UseHttpGet** property to
>   **true** might pose a security risk for
>   your application if you are working
>   with sensitive data or transactions.
>   In GET requests, the message is
>   encoded by the browser into the URL
>   and is therefore an easier target for
>   tampering.

Comment: this works fine if you add the following to your web.config

<webServices>
 <protocols>
  <add name="HttpGet" />
  <add name="HttpPost" />
 </protocols>
</webServices>

Comment: Adding the web config was all i needed. Didn't even need to decorate the method.

Comment: All I had to do was add the web.config entry and it worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

ASMX web services use SOAP. SOAP requests use only POST to invoke methods. You will need to generate a proxy client in your aspx page to invoke the web service. If you really need to use GET verbs to invoke web services you might need to use a different approach such as [WCF REST](http://www.techbubbles.com/wcf/wcf-and-rest/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that article says that WCF REST also defaults to POST and SOAP, not sure how that's an improvement!