# asmx service with query string

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I have a asmx service with a single input query.

http://service.asmx/Userdetails?UserID=1

is it possible to call this service with the URL: http://service.asmx/Userdetails/userID/1 
or http://service.asmx/Userdetails/1

Comment: Try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006828/possible-to-invoke-asmx-service-with-parameter-via-url-query-string

Answer (score 1):

.asmx services use `SOAP` approach, which simply is having method with parameters and calling it from code.
What you want is `REST`, methods can be called from simple `GET` methods or from browser like URL you have provided.

If you decide to use REST style than [ASP.NET Web.Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) is easy and powerfull tool for building REST services.